# How to calculate combination of Data frame in R

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, combinations

I am a beginner in R program.
I imported a csv file. This file only contains one column with 50 characters, but R classifies it as a dataframe. I need all possible combinations within elements of this column. I think I need to work with a vector not with a data frame, how can I do it? 
Thank you!

Comment: If you are using `read.table` or `read.csv` it will read as a data.frame.  Perhaps you need `?scan` and `combn`.  `v1 <- scan("yourfile.csv", sep=",", what = "", quiet=TRUE); combn(v1, 2)`

Comment: or extract the column from the imported data frame like: vector <- df$column

Comment: If you post some code, an example of this column of 50 characters you describe, and a psuedo example of what sort of computation you'd like to do, it might be easier for others to suggest ways to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Thank you everyone. Your answers were very helpful. Finally I did it with @akrun 's answer, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your data frame already contains the vector you need. You can call it with

```
dataframe$column_name
```

The text before the $ operator specifies your data frame, and after is your vector, which is a column in your data frame. So when you run your calculations you can just write

```
function(dataframe$column_name)
```

In your specific case with a single vector, it may be simplest to change the dataframe into a 2d vector. But when you start manipulating your data, you'll likely store more vectors of variables. You'll want to keep those vectors organized within data frames.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `unlist`?
You can use it to change a data frame into a vector, then you can use `combn` to get combination.